# Adding Tab to a standard dataTable | SQL, PHP, HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables, sqlsrv

May I ask for assistance on how to set this up into holding data for second table? I currently have a standard dataTable. I tried to use the guides for configuration, but I ultimately failed. Is there a way to do this without changing much of my current code? These are the codes.

**This is for Table 1**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Series No.</th>
        <th>Account Type</th>
        <th>Tools</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
          echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                <td>
                <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
          ";
        }
      ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is for Table 2**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Series No.</th>
        <th>Account Type</th>
        <th>Tools</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accountcode";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
          echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                <td>
                <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
          ";
        }
      ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to configure it using this documentation https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html but I failed to do it.

**This is currently my script**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.edit', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
    });

    $("body").on('click', '.delete', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#delete').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
    });
});

function getRow(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'account_type_row.php',
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            $('.decid').val(response.seriesno);
            $('#edit_account_type_id').val(response.seriesno);
            $('#edit_accounttype').val(response.accounttype);
            $('#edit_accounttitle').val(response.accounttitle);
            $('#edit_accounttype').val(response.accounttype);
            $('#approve_account_type_id').val(response.account_type_id);
            $('#approve_accounttype').val(response.accounttype);
            $('#approve_accounttitle').val(response.accounttitle);
            $('#approve_accounttype').val(response.accounttype);
            $('#edit_postedby').val(response.postedby);
            $('#del_account_type').html(response.account_type);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And this is the universal script that I made to lessen the codes all together.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#example1').DataTable({
      responsive: true
    })
    $('#example2').DataTable({ //backup for forture unique table
      responsive: true
    })
    $('#example3').DataTable({ //backup for forture unique table
      responsive: true
    })
    $('#example4').DataTable({ //backup for forture unique table
      responsive: true
    })
    $('#example5').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
</script>
```

How will I approach this? May I ask for help?

Comment: By making your queries directly in your templates like this you are making it much harder for yourself to build this in a conventional way, If you followed a more best-practices approach of separating your code concerns you may get more useful advice here.

Comment: @JPSilvashy do you have a link or something that I can study? I really need to check on this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, depending on how large you anticipate your project becoming, you may want to look at a framework like Laravel, in terms of general concepts, MVC is a popular design pattern used in PHP to separate concerns and structure an application. https://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html [1] https://laravel.com/ [2]